# Function is not getting stopped at return at if conditions

Tags: python, function, if-statement, return, break

I'm new to python, this below funtion is not getting stop at if condition where it needs to stop.

```
def check_pi_installation_status():
   proc1cmd = "grep " + AppName
   p1 = subprocess.Popen(['kubectl', 'get', 'pi', '-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   p2 = subprocess.Popen(proc1cmd, shell=True, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   p1.stdout.close()
   stdout_list = p2.communicate()[0] 
   stdout_list = stdout_list.decode()
   imagenamepi = stdout_list.split()
   print("pi imagename ", imagenamepi)


   if (imagenamepi[2] == 'Installed'):
     print("Successfully Installed")
     return
   if (imagenamepi[2] == 'Failed'):
     print(" Installation Failed")
     return
   if(imagenamepi[2] != 'Installed' and imagenamepi[2] != 'Failed'):
     time.sleep(30)
     # count = count + 1
     # print("count", count)
     write_eventslog()
     check_pi_installation_status()
```

Below are the case:

1. when i started this function where its still not reached to 'Failed',it prints 'Installation Failed' on reaching state 'Failed' but it continues even when it reaches 'Failed' state.
2. I ran the function when state is already 'Failed' its works as expected (it prints 'Installation Failed' and come out.

Comment: your third condition is redundant. if the two conditions above haven't triggered, the third one will execute always, so the conditional is not needed

Comment: Doing this recursively will fail if it needs to try more than 1000 times (or whatever your recursion limit is). I'd write the "try until it succeeds" as a separate function with a loop.

Comment: There's no possible way this function could continue running after printing "Installation Failed".  The problem must be elsewhere in the program.

Comment: Thanks @SembeiNorimaki make note of comments :) much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @kindall, i make note of comments :) much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @JohnGordon, i make note of comments :) much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using multiple if statements, why not use if, elif and else? The main difference here is that when you have multiple if statements, all of them will  run no matter what, so change it to this:

```
if (imagenamepi[2] == 'Installed'):
     print("Successfully Installed")
     return
elif (imagenamepi[2] == 'Failed'):
     print(" Installation Failed")
     return
else:
     time.sleep(30)
     # count = count + 1
     # print("count", count)
     write_eventslog()
     check_pi_installation_status()
```

Over here, we first used **if**, then **elif**. **elif** is a mixture between IF and ELSE, which basically tells the compiler: If the statement above did not run, check this one. You can have multiple elif's in one go. Lastly, we have **else**. Else tells the compiler: If none of the other statements ran, run this one. Unlike Elif, you can only have one Else condition.

The main difference between the two methods are that when you use If, Elif and Else, the entire statement is exited when a condition is run.

Although im not too sure why return doesnt exit out the function immediately, the use of elif and else would help you do the same thing. More than likely, it works on the **fail** state because none of the other two statements are applicable.

Comment: Thanks its working for my scenario. is there any way where i can also stop execution of parent loop which has this function inside.?

Comment: @ManjuManohar You could return some special value from this function, and then the caller could check the returned value and decide to stop its loop.

Comment: there is a statement for this. whenever you want to stop a loop prematurely, break can be used. Just put the break statement after each return, if that doesn't work put it before the return or remove the return altogether.